# I am not able to see my picture in ImagevView

Tags: android, android-intent

I am not getting my picture (clickable picture) in `ImageView`.
These images are clicked but I’m not able to show them in `ImageView`.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn,btn1;
    ImageView iv;
    Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(intent,101);
            }
        });


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmp);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share picture with..."));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Uri picturePath=data.getData();
        iv.setImageURI(picturePath);
        try {
            Bundle b=data.getExtras();
            bmp=(Bitmap) b.get("Data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (Exception  e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: try replacing bmp=(Bitmap) b.get("Data"); with bmp=(Bitmap) b.get("data"); the tag is case sensitive

Comment: Here's a reference for @NikosHidalgo : https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskCaptureIntent `under the key "data"`.

Comment: Thanks you sir @NikosHidalgo

Answer (score 0):

Intent Permission "FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION" is missing in intent.try to add permission with addFlags line in Intent.

Ex:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmp);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share picture with..."));
```